# Why is it necessary in confidential transactions to have two generators?

Tags: cryptography, confidential-transactions

So as i understand it (though im not sure if its the same w/ bulletproofs so please correct me if im wrong), a commitment is generated like this;

```
commitment = (blinding_secret . G) + (value . H)
```

where G and H are both different generators on the same curve. But why is it necessary to have the second generator, H, instead of just using G twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `C = xG + aH` where `a` is the amount and `x` is the blinding factor.

The point of a Pedersen Commitment is to commit you to a certain value of `a`. If instead you had `C = xG + aG`, then this simplifies to `C = (x+a)G`. So you could claim any value of `a` later by claiming you'd used a different blinding factor. Using H, which has an unknown DL w.r.t. G, prevents you from doing this.

Comment: And this is how commitments are calculated in the current version of monero as well? Or is there some variation because of bulletproofs?

Comment: @cookiekid There has been no change to commitment construction